# How to read the arguments in the function 'min'?

Tags: c++

```
   template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b);
```

1)variable 'a' is address to constant class 'T';

2)variable 'b' is address to constant class 'T';

are these statements 1 and 2 true?

Comment: Any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should explain what *reference* is (and the difference between `&` operator in different contexts).

Comment: Is there an option #4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `a` and `b` are constant reference to instance of T.